# is it possible to do 3way handshake only one time with mqtt communication?

Tags: ssl, mqtt, iot, tls1.2, mosquitto

I am using mosquitto_pub to publish the data with TLS using a topic.
I am using mosquitto_sub to subscribe to the topic from mosquitto_pub..

Whenever I fire a mosquitto_pub , I noticed that the wireshark can detect a 3 way handshake each time.
My Question now is, is it possible for mosquitto to do only one time of a 3 way handshake? just to minimize the time of sending the data and receiving it to the other end.

I mean like keep the handshake alive on the first firing of mosquitto_pub, then on the succeeding publishing of message, it will send only the TLS data and not do a 3 way handshake over and over again each time.

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve here?

Comment: the minimalization of the handshake. because during mosquitto_pub + TLS , i can see in the wireshark that the flow takes awhile before the TLS protected data is being sent due to the TLS handshake.... so is there a way to be able to just have a one time 3 way handshake, so that the succeeding message to be published is gonna be just the TLS protected data itself and no need to execute the 3 way handshake again ?

Comment: Yes, but why is that a problem? If you are going to be sending multiple messages then why not write your own publishing client using one of the many libraries and maintain a constant connection to the broker?

Comment: do you have a sample ?, because the "-k" OR "-keepalive" parameter is not the one am looking for. because it doesn't stop the 3 way handshake each time i publish a message

Comment: I'm saying `mosquitto_pub` is the wrong tool for sending multiple messages. There are literally 100s of MQTT client libraries you could use to write your own.

Comment: but this client libraries you're referring to are just wrappers to cover the mosquitto_pub, correct ?

Comment: No, they are not

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing is SSL/TLS session resumption.

There is support in the `mosquitto` broker for session resumption, but not in the command line tools.

This is because they would need to store the session id key between each execution. This looks to have been discussed in [this](https://www.eclipse.org/lists/mosquitto-dev/msg01606.html) mosquitto-dev mailing list thread, but not implemented as there was no demand for it.

You can use TLS session resumption with the Paho C library by settings the Clean Session flag to false (I still think the concept of MQTT session and TLS session should have been kept separate) if the broker supports it.

Comment: I have checked the existing mosquitto libraries, neither the library built for PHP nor Python has a support for one time run of a 3way handshake of a TLS communication. these existing client libraries mostly supports port 1883 transmission only. and none for port 8883

Comment: That is not true, I've never looked at the PHP libraries, but the Python library definitely supports TLS connections and since connections are persistent there is no need to worry about the cost of the TLS handshake as it will only be done once.

Comment: Also, why are you only looking at the moquitto libraries and not the MQTT libraries in general?

Comment: it's just naming preference. anyway, is my understanding of the flow of mqtt correct ?  ... 1) in the remote server, I ran mosquitto -c /etc/config.conf ..then in the same server, I ran mosquitto_sub + blah blah parameters in another terminal tab.... then in my other computer, I use mosquitto_pub to publish the message .